# railsのフォームでカラムごとにエラーを表示させたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在`errors.full_messages.each`を使って全部のエラーを一箇所に表示しています。

これをエラーがでたカラムごとのすぐ上に表示に表示するようにしたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: [plataformatec/simple_form: Forms made easy for Rails! It's tied to a simple DSL, with no opinion on markup.](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) を使うと良いと思いますが、あくまで自前で実装したいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ベタに書くなら、属性ごとに `errors.full_messages_for(:属性)` で配列として取得できる(エラーがなければ空配列)ので、その結果を利用してコツコツ整形出力すればよいと思います。